# Избавится от двухсторонней зависимости классов

Tags: java, многопоточность, ооп, инспекция-кода

Есть программа которая осуществляет поиск строки по файлам в заданной директории. После сбора всех `txt` файлов запускается несколько потоков, которые этот поиск и осуществляют. И когда один из потоков находит совпадение, он останавливает циклы остальных потоков через `interrupted()` и вызывает у класса `ConsumerOfSearch` метод `accept()`.

Код рабочий, но проблема в том что его монолитность просто зашкаливает. И я хочу переделать это в нормальный человеческий код, но не знаю как.

Помогите пожалуйста его переделать так что-бы избавиться от двухсторонних зависимостей.
Больше всего беспокоят зависимости между `ParallelSearch` и `SearchByFileContent`.

Класс который создает и работает с пулом потоков:

```
public class ParallelSearch implements Parallel {
    // обернутая ссылка на класс хранящий результат поиска на полях
    private AtomicReference<Consumer<File>> consumer;
    // останавливает все потоки (вызывает cancel в цикле по threads).
    private final Stopper stopper;
    // лист запущенных потоков.
    private final List<Future<File>> threads;
    // размер пула потоков.
    private final int amountThreads;
    // очередь в которой храняться файлы.
    private final Queue<File> container;
    private final ExecutorService service;

    public ParallelSearch(final int amountThreads, final Consumer<File> consumer) {
        this.service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(amountThreads);
        this.amountThreads = amountThreads;

        this.container = new LinkedTransferQueue<>();
        this.consumer =  new AtomicReference<>(consumer);
        this.threads =   new ArrayList<>(amountThreads);
        this.stopper =   new Stopper();
    }

    @Override
    public AtomicReference<Consumer<File>> getConsumer() {
        return consumer;
    }


    @Override
    public void killConsumerReference() {
        this.consumer = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startParallelSearch(
            final String pathToRoot,
            final String targetText) {

        this.searchByFileSystem(pathToRoot);
        this.searchByFilesContent(targetText);
    }

    // поток обходит файловую систему в поисках txt файлов и добавляет в очередь.
    private void searchByFileSystem(final String pathToRoot) {
        final Thread searchByFileSystem = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CollectingTXTFiles(
                        pathToRoot, container)
                        .collectTXTFromRoot();
            }
        });
        searchByFileSystem.start();
        try {
            searchByFileSystem.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // добавляем в пул потоки для поиска строки по содержимому txt файлов
    private void searchByFilesContent(final String targetText) {
        for (int i = 0; i < (this.amountThreads - 1); i++) {
            if (service.isShutdown()) break;
            final Future<File> taskRead =
                    this.service.submit(new Callable<File>() {
                        @Override
                        public File call() throws Exception {
                            return new SearchByFileContent(container, stopper, ParallelSearch.this)
                                    .scanQueue(targetText);
                        }
                    });
            // добавляем в потоки поиск контенту
            this.threads.add(taskRead);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Останавливает все потоки ссылка его экземпляр есть у всех потоков.
     * Если один из потоков найдет искомую строку, вызовет stopAllSearchingThread().
     */
    class Stopper {
        void stopAllSearchingThread() {
            for (Future future : threads) {
                future.cancel(true);
            }
            service.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Его интерфейс:

```
public interface Parallel {
    void startParallelSearch(final String pathToRoot, final String targetText);
    void killConsumerReference();
    AtomicReference<Consumer<File>> getConsumer();
}
```

И потоки которые ищут по содержимому файлов:

```
public interface SearchByFile {
    File scanQueue(final String target);
}

public class SearchByFileContent implements SearchByFile {
    private final Queue<File> paths;
    private final ParallelSearch.Stopper stopper;
    private final Parallel parallelSearch;

    public SearchByFileContent(final Queue<File> paths,
                               final ParallelSearch.Stopper stopper,
                               final Parallel parallelSearch) {
        this.stopper = stopper;
        this.paths = paths;
        this.parallelSearch = parallelSearch;
    }

    @Override
    public File scanQueue(final String target) {
        while (this.paths.size() != 0 && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            final File result = getFileWhichContains(target, this.paths.poll());
            if (result != null && !result.getName().equals("-1")) {
                if (parallelSearch.getConsumer() != null) {
                    synchronized (parallelSearch.getConsumer()) {
                        if (this.parallelSearch.getConsumer().get() != null) {
                            this.parallelSearch.getConsumer().get().accept(result);
                            this.parallelSearch.killConsumerReference();
                            this.stopper.stopAllSearchingThread();
                            return result;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return new File("-1");
    }

    private File getFileWhichContains(final String target, final File file) {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (file == null) return new File("-1");
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(file))
        ) {

            String line;
            while (Objects.nonNull(line = reader.readLine())) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            if (new String(sb).contains(target)) {
                return file;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new File("-1");
    }
}
```

Сам Consumer не слишком затейлив:

```
public class ConsumerOfSearch implements ConsumerGetter<File> {
    private File result = null;

    @Override
    public void accept(File result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    @Override
    public File getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}
```

Его интерфейс:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public interface ConsumerGetter<F extends File> extends Consumer<F> {
    F getResult();
}
```

И сбор `txt` файлов по файловой системе, в проблеме он не участвует, но для полной картины:

```
public interface Collector {
    void collectTXTFromRoot();
}

public class CollectingTXTFiles implements Collector {
    private final String root;
    private final Queue<File> files;

    public CollectingTXTFiles(final String root,
                              final Queue<File> files) {
        this.root = root;
        this.files = files;
    }

    @Override
    public void collectTXTFromRoot() throws IllegalArgumentException {
        final File root = new File(this.root);

        if (!root.exists() || !root.isDirectory()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(
                    "Directory: '%s' not found", this.root));
        }

        this.selectTXTFiles(root);
    }

    private void selectTXTFiles(final File file) {
        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            return;
        }

        if (file.getName().endsWith(".txt") &&
                !file.isDirectory()) {

            this.files.add(file);
        }

        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            final File[] childes = file.listFiles();
            assert Objects.nonNull(childes);

            for (File f : childes) {
                selectTXTFiles(f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот запуск:

```
public class StartApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Menu menu = new Menu();
        menu.start();
    }
}

class ConsoleInput {
    private Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String getAnswer() {
        return scanner.nextLine();
    }
}

class Menu {
    private ConsoleInput consoleInput = new ConsoleInput();

    void start() {
        System.out.println("Enter directory : ");
        final String dir = consoleInput.getAnswer();
        System.out.println("Enter target text : ");
        final String targetText = consoleInput.getAnswer();
        ConsumerGetter<File> consumer = new ConsumerOfSearch();
        Parallel parallel = new ParallelSearch(5, consumer);
        parallel.startParallelSearch(dir, targetText);

        int sec = 4;
        while (sec != 0) {
            if (consumer.getResult() != null) break;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            sec--;
        }

        if (consumer.getResult() == null) {
            System.out.println("Time is wait is over. File not exist.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("target text contains in : "
                    + consumer.getResult().getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

Буду очень признателен за любые конструктивные идеи  или просто мысли, как избавиться от монолитности, особенно между `ParallelSearch` и `SearchByFileContent`.

Comment: добавьте в вопрос все интерфейсы, которые вы создали

Comment: как вы это все запускаете?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman добавил запуск